# Compare two tables data and check the checkbox with same data

Tags: php

I have two tables in my db. The structure is as follows:

```
Comparitive_st_sup

================
id | item_name
================
486 | Item1
487 | Item2
488 | Item3
489 | Item4
=================

quotation_items

=====================
item_id | item_name
=====================
487     | Item2
489     | Item4
=====================
```

What i want to achieve is Firstly i need to display all the records from the table1 that is 'comparitive_st_sup'. Secondly, there is a checkbox infront of the displayed records. Then i need to compare the data from table 2 that is 'quotation_items'. That is if id=item_id then checkbox should be checked. below is the code iam trying its checking the records but not all records are checked. Am i making any mistake?

```
<?php
include('config.php');

$sql = "SELECT item_id FROM quotation_items WHERE tender_id=150002";
$query_resource = mysql_query($sql);
$quotation = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_resource);

$quotation_rec = explode(',', $quotation['item_id']);

$sql = "SELECT id from comparitive_st_sup where tender_id=150002";
$query_resource = mysql_query($sql);
$comparitive = Array(); 
  while($name = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_resource))
  {
      ?>
      <span><?php echo $name['id']; ?></span>
      <input type="checkbox" name="comparitive[]" value="<?php echo $name['id']; ?>" <?php if(in_array($name['id'], $quotation_rec)): ?> checked='checked' <?php endif; ?>/><br />

  <?php } ?>
```

@ Stefen, following script i tried to attempt your code:

```
<?php
include('config.php');

$sql = "SELECT c.id FROM comparitive_st_sup c LEFT JOIN quotation_items q ON c.id = q.item_id WHERE c.tender_id=150002";

//$sql = "SELECT id from comparitive_st_sup where tender_id=150002";
$query_resource = mysql_query($sql);
$comparitive = Array(); 
  while($name = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_resource))
  {
      ?>
      <span><?php echo $name['id']; ?></span>
<input type="checkbox" name="comparitive[]" value="<?php echo $name['id']; ?>" <?php if(null !== $name['item_id']): ?> checked='checked' <?php endif; ?>/><br />  <?php } ?>
```

Comment: `mysql_*` is deprecated. Please read http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated

Comment: Yes i know..iam just editing some code already developed by someone... Iam trying to rectify some errors..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your select statements you refer to a field `tender_id` which you did not mention in your DB structure. Assuming it is present in both tables you should check if the rows that should match this field actually has the value `150002`.

Also you could optimize the code using a single query like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT c.id FROM comparitive_st_sup c LEFT JOIN quotation_items q ON c.id = q.item_id WHERE c.tender_id=150002";
```

and

```
<input type="checkbox" name="comparitive[]" value="<?php echo $name['id']; ?>" <?php if(null !== $name['item_id']): ?> checked='checked' <?php endif; ?>/><br />
```

as your output.

Comment: Yes, tender_id is present in both the tables. i was just checking the script, but its just outputting the records, with out any checks in the cehckboxes....

Comment: Do u want me to edit my question and wanna update your code which i have tried?